# multiple where statements in proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

I'm not a frequent SQL user so be patient:) What I'm trying to do is create multiple summary columns using SQL proc; I know the below is incorrect as I can't use where statement like this but how do I rearrange this?

```
proc sql ; 
    create table totals as 
        select
            Account_number,
            sum(charge) as total_payments,
            sum(charge) as total_cash (where transactioncode in ('CASH')),
            sum(charge) as total_intt (where transactioncode in ('INTT')),
            calculated total_payments/12 as avg_monthly_payments,
            calculated total_cash/12 as avg_cash_payments,
            calculated total_intt/12 as avg_INTT_payments
        from        tabe_1
        group by    Account_number
; quit ;
```

Comment: For your divisions of 12, is this hardcoded for a reason, or is there a way to determine this from the data, ie the number of rows or using the MEAN()/AVG() function instead? If so, a summary task such as PROC MEANS/SUMMARY may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CASE...WHEN** statement, something like this

```
 create table totals as 
    select
       Account_number,
       sum(charge) as total_payments,
       sum(CASE WHEN transactioncode ='CASH' THEN   charge ELSE 0 END) as total_cash,
       sum(CASE WHEN transactioncode ='INTT' THEN   charge ELSE 0 END) as total_intt,
       sum(charge)/12 as avg_monthly_payments,
       sum(CASE WHEN transactioncode ='CASH' THEN   charge ELSE 0 END)/12 avg_cash_payments,
       sum(CASE WHEN transactioncode ='INIT' THEN   charge ELSE 0 END)/12 as avg_INTT_payments
    from        tabe_1
    group by    Account_number
```

Comment: I believe in SAS you may have to run `CASE` statements in subquery then aggregate the columns in main query. And best to use `calculated` as OP does to avoid re-running calculation.

Comment: @Parfait is right, that would be better, I wrote this to do all in one statement, which is not required